# How is #define S64_MIN defined in linux data types?

Tags: c++, c, linux, c++11, linux-kernel

I am trying to understand the definition of a linux macro `S64_MIN` used in the following  `else` condition i.e. `draw = S64_MIN`.

Which exact decimal value is meant here for `S64_MIN`?

```
        if (weights[i]) 
          {
            u = hash(bucket->h.hash, x, ids[i], r);
            u &= 0xffff;
            ln = crush_ln(u) - 0x1000000000000ll;
            
            __s64 draw = div64_s64(ln, weights[i]);
        } 
else   
       {
            __s64 draw = S64_MIN;  
           
          // #define S64_MAX    ((s64)(U64_MAX >> 1))
          // #define S64_MIN    ((s64)(-S64_MAX -1))
       }
        if (i == 0 || draw > high_draw) 
            
          {
            high = i;
            high_draw = draw;
          }
    }
    return bucket->h.items[high];
}
```

Comment: What keeps you from just printing them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can look up these macro definitions in [Linux source code](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/include/linux/limits.h#L24):

```
#define U64_MAX     ((u64)~0ULL)
#define S64_MAX     ((s64)(U64_MAX >> 1))
#define S64_MIN     ((s64)(-S64_MAX - 1))
```

This means:

- `U64_MAX` has all bits set to 1.
- Then  `S64_MAX` has all but the highest bit set to 1.
- And finally, `S64_MIN` will have only the highest bit set.

```
U64_MAX: 1111 1111 ... 1111 = 0xFFFF FFFF FFFF FFFF = 18,446,744,073,709,551,615
S64_MAX: 0111 1111 ... 1111 = 0x7FFF FFFF FFFF FFFF =  9,223,372,036,854,775,807
S64_MIN: 1000 0000 ... 0000 = 0x8000 0000 0000 0000 = -9,223,372,036,854,775,808
```

Comment: Thanks ! So basically the decimal value here is equivalent to 9,223,372,036,854,775,808, right?

Comment: U64_MIN is 0. Definitely not all 1’s.

Comment: @0andriy thanks for the hint. It is `U64_MAX` as seen in code snippet. Fixed the typo.

Answer (score 0):

S64_MIN is the minimum value (maximum negative value) that can be represented by a signed 64-bit integer.

```
#   define S64_MAX  9223372036854775807LL
#   define S64_MIN  (-S64_MAX - 1LL)
```